# What is this Data Type (Get Request) bit.ly oauth2

Tags: php, html, json, curl

```
{ "status_code": 200, "status_txt": "OK", "data": { "long_url": "http:\/\/google.com\/", "url": "http:\/\/bit.ly\/17A2GVj", "hash": "17A2GVj", "global_hash": "3j4ir4", "new_hash": 0 } }
```

I get something like this after i do a

```
$curl = curl_init();
// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api-ssl.bitly.com/v3/shorten?access_token=xxx&longUrl=http%3A%2F%2Fgoogle.com%2F',
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/4.0'
));
// Send the request & save response to $resp
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);

echo $resp;
```

How do i read "hash"

Comment: [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) on `$resp`

Comment: @pNre how do i read the item? do i have to like loop object(stdClass) first?

Comment: `$object->data->hash`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$respObj = json_decode($resp);
echo $respObj->data->hash;
```

`json_decode`, by default, returns an instance of `stdClass`. Access `stdClass`' members with `->`.

Comment: Is it true that data represents any form of ["something"] no matter which object it's in?

Comment: @RainbowHat If I understand your question correctly, no: `data` in this case is specific to the object structure within `$respObj`. You could also access the status code of 200 via `$respObj->status_code` and this has nothing to do with `data`. You are also mixing array and object notation, `["something"]` is different than `->something` (respectively).