# Retrieving data in object(stdClass)#2

Tags: php, html

```
object(stdClass)#1 (3) { ["status_code"]=> int(200) ["status_txt"]=> string(2) "OK" ["data"]=> 
object(stdClass)#2 (5) { ["long_url"]=> string(18) "http://google.com/" ["url"]=> string(21) "http://bit.ly/17A2GVj" ["hash"]=> string(7) "17A2GVj" ["global_hash"]=> string(6) "3j4ir4" ["new_hash"]=> int(0) } }
```

How do i loop this? i'm trying to get ["hash"]

Comment: `<pre>` tag is your friend. Use `echo '<pre>'.print_r($object, true).'<pre';` to get a neater output.

Comment: repost of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19346928/what-is-this-data-type-get-request-bit-ly-oauth2 ?

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach $objects as $object
{
   $result[] = $object['data']
}
```

var_dump($result);

Answer (score 0):

`$yourObjectVariable->data->hash`